# How to start new activity from recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I want to start new activity and also passing JSON data to the new activity when i click an item on the recyclerview. i followed a video in youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OfsiccfUWVc&index=6&list=PLaoF-xhnnrRW_FGeacuT1VLqnRMKfpp4v but the video didn't show how to go to new activity once i clicked the item on recyclerview. from the video, i wanted to click on the item and then new activity will bring me to the 'more detail page' about the item.

i have tried to do the intent but i am not sure how to call from the new main activity

this is my adapter code:

```
public class LonghouseAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LonghouseViewHolder> {

Context context;
List<LonghousesCategoryOne> longhousesCategoryOneList;
List<Category> categories;
private OnItemClickListener mlistener;


public LonghouseAdapter(Context context, List<LonghousesCategoryOne> longhousesCategoryOneList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.longhousesCategoryOneList = longhousesCategoryOneList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public LonghouseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.longhouse_item_layout,null);
    return new LonghouseViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LonghouseViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.txt_price.setText(new StringBuilder("").append(longhousesCategoryOneList.get(position).Price));
    holder.txt_longhouse_name.setText(new StringBuilder("").append(longhousesCategoryOneList.get(position).Name));

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(longhousesCategoryOneList.get(position).Link)
            .into(holder.img_longhouse);

    holder.setItemClickListener(new IItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Common.currentCategory = categories.get(position);

           context.startActivity(new Intent(context, descriptionsActivity.class));
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return longhousesCategoryOneList.size();
}
}
```

this is my viewholder code:

```
public class LonghouseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageView img_longhouse;
TextView txt_longhouse_name, txt_price;



public void setItemClickListener(IItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
    this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
}

IItemClickListener itemClickListener;


public LonghouseViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    img_longhouse = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_longhouse);
    txt_longhouse_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_longhouse_name);
    txt_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_longhouse_price);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    itemClickListener.onClick(v);
}
}
```

in my descriptionActivity, how do i set the item to my xml view?so far i have done this.

```
public class descriptionsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

retreatSecondApi mservice;
ImageView img_longhouse;
TextView txt_longhouse_description, txt_price;
Context context;
List<LonghousesCategoryOne> longhousesCategoryOneList;

CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mservice = Common.getAPI();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_descriptions);

    img_longhouse = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.placeImageView);
    txt_longhouse_description = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.placeDescTextView);
    txt_price = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_longhouse_price);

    txt_longhouse_description.setText()

}


}
```

Can anyone guide me on this? Thank you

Comment: You are doing it right.
 inside onclick listener, uncomment the code

Answer (score 1):

As @rgaraisayev recommends in your **onClick()** listener uncomment the call to **startActivity()** i.e.

```
holder.setItemClickListener(new IItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Common.currentCategory = categories.get(position);
        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, descriptionsActivity.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it, so in my holder view:

```
  holder.setItemClickListener(new IItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Common.longhousedesc  = longhousesCategoryOneList.get(position);



           context.startActivity(new Intent(context, descriptionsActivity.class));
        }
        });
```

and in my new activity, i bind the data to my xml view like this:

```
txt_longhouse_description.setText(Common.longhousedesc.descriptions);
```